# Have a google compute cloud instance - what's my password?

Tags: google-compute-engine

So I have successfully setup a VM instance and can remote desktop in.  I've been using it for a while now - but I am stumped as to what my password is.   For instance - I need to unlock my default keyring but I don't know my password.    Another example:  I can't 'sudo' anything in terminal because I don't know my password.  All the logins occur through my console/console SSL and remotedesktop.google.com so I simply don't know what my password on the machine itself is!   Thoughts?

Comment: I've tried on my linux VM and I can run commands with `sudo` without typing password. Do you use [OS Login](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/managing-instance-access)? If yes, which IAM roles do you have configured for your account: `roles/compute.osLogin` which doesn't grant administrator permissions or `roles/compute.osAdminLogin` which grants administrator permissions? Could you please provide a few examples from VM command line?

Comment: Please check at `/etc/group` if your username is a member of `google-sudoers` and update your question with a result.

Comment: @SerhiiRohoza I don't use OS Login as frankly I don't know how, despite GCE's prompts to get me to upgrade.   Checking on the file you cite gives me only: 
google-sudoers:x:1000:
myusername:x:1001:
I'm not sure what this means in terms of your question?

Comment: Thanks! It's more clear now. Please try to use a startup script from [another my answer](https://serverfault.com/a/1049810/551540) and set password for your account. Let me know if you problem will be solved.

Comment: Have you tried to create a new VM instance and check if you see the same behavior with `sudo`?

Comment: Have you solved your issue?